# getting eclipse to syntax color php functions

Tags: php, eclipse, syntax-highlighting, dreamweaver, eclipse-pdt

I want to color native PHP functions in eclipse and differentiate them from user defined functions

so if I type in abs()...I want that color to change and have it of different color compared to a user defined function....similar to how it works in dreamweaver

how do i do this in eclipse

note I have eclipse PDT Helios 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried going to File Associations and setting *.php -> PHP Editor manually?

(Sorry, that's under Eclipse -> Preferences -> General -> Editors.)

Answer (score 0):

turns out that eclipse does not support this....nil